# Caching Images From Remote Server in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching, uiimageview

Hi i have some images stored in cache. I need the cache images to be stored in my directories.

i tried the following methods `EgoImageview`and following two methods

```
- (UIImage *) getImage: (NSString *) ImageURLString;
- (void) cacheImage: (NSString *) ImageURLString;
```

But in this the caching is not working in the proper way

Following is the code of `cache image fn`

pls suggest me some better ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
NSString *imgURL = @"imagUrl";

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];

[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```